# Dockerfile with Tomcat: "exec: catalina.sh" no such file or directory

Tags: java, bash, tomcat, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to get my web app working with Tomcat on Docker. However, I'm having a bit of trouble getting this actually working. I'm brand new to both Tomcat and Docker and don't quite know what I'm doing wrong.

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM java:8-jre
#https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat

ENV CATALINA_HOME ~/Tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p "$CATALINA_HOME"
WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME

# see https://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/KEYS
RUN gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys \
    05AB33110949707C93A279E3D3EFE6B686867BA6 \
    07E48665A34DCAFAE522E5E6266191C37C037D42 \
    47309207D818FFD8DCD3F83F1931D684307A10A5 \
    541FBE7D8F78B25E055DDEE13C370389288584E7 \
    61B832AC2F1C5A90F0F9B00A1C506407564C17A3 \
    79F7026C690BAA50B92CD8B66A3AD3F4F22C4FED \
    9BA44C2621385CB966EBA586F72C284D731FABEE \
    A27677289986DB50844682F8ACB77FC2E86E29AC \
    A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7 \
    DCFD35E0BF8CA7344752DE8B6FB21E8933C60243 \
    F3A04C595DB5B6A5F1ECA43E3B7BBB100D811BBE \
    F7DA48BB64BCB84ECBA7EE6935CD23C10D498E23

ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR 8
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION 8.0.38
ENV TOMCAT_TGZ_URL https://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-$TOMCAT_MAJOR/v$TOMCAT_VERSION/bin/apache-tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz

#RUN set -x \
#   && curl -fSL "$TOMCAT_TGZ_URL" -o tomcat.tar.gz \
#   && curl -fSL "$TOMCAT_TGZ_URL.asc" -o tomcat.tar.gz.asc \
#   && gpg --verify tomcat.tar.gz.asc \
#   && tar -xvf tomcat.tar.gz --strip-components=1 \
#   && rm bin/*.bat \
#   && rm tomcat.tar.gz*

#ENTRYPOINT ["$CATALINA_HOME/bin/./catalina.sh"]

#RUN chmod +x $CATALINA_HOME/bin

ADD ./target/*.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

This was taken primarily from https://www.distelli.com/docs/tutorials/build-and-deploy-tomcat-war-docker/.

I was getting an issue of

> "exec: \"catalina.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"

So, after doing some poking around I tried making catalina.sh executable by running

> chmod +x $CATALINA_HOME/bin/"./catalina.sh"

But then it said it couldn't find $CATALINA_HOME/bin/"./catalina.sh". So, I tried making it ENTRYPOINT but that didn't work.

From the terminal I *was* able to successfully run

> chmod +x $CATALINA_HOME/bin/"./catalina.sh"

but that didn't clear up the issue.

What am I doing wrong? Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use tomcat base image? as in https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/
Working DockerFile.

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8 
COPY ./target/*.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps
```

Comment: I still run into issues with `CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]`

Comment: Try using Tomcat base image like this `FROM tomcat:7-jre7` . You will not have to have Tomcat commands on your DockerFile. Plain copying of wars would suffice.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how do I copy the .war to the Tomcat image running in docker? I tried `docker cp PATH_TO_WARFILE tomcat:8.0` but it doesn't seem to be able to find it. Especially if I wanted to add it as the ROOT.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy . Destination should be a valid filepath that will be used by the Tomcat image. I think you can use $CATALINA_HOME/webapps .

Comment: I guess i'm asking what's the directory that I put it in? There's no `tomcat:8.0/webapps` so where do i copy it to? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The `COPY` command that am talking about is to be present on the DockerFile(not given as a standalone command). The destination should be $CATALINA_HOME/webapps typically and this will be accessible only after the run command as this will reside within the container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154927/discussion-between-cooltoad-and-livingrobot).